# iPhone + Quartz: How to get a water effect

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, graphics, quartz-graphics

ist there any chance to build a water effect with Quartz on the iPhone?

Something similar to this one:

[alt text http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/6358/bild1wbm.png](http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/6358/bild1wbm.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For that, I highly recommend using OpenGL ES**.

Despite the "simplicity" of the problem you addressed in [**this SO question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845662/core-animation-or-opengl-es), I recommended OpenGL ES then as well. So, you can imagine why I'm advising it again.

Check **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726738/how-do-i-make-a-water-effect-view-with-opengles-on-the-iphone)** for the water effect with OpenGL.