# water animation in iphone app

Tags: iphone, animation

I want to show water flowing from one container to another in iphone app.

Can some suggest me how to do it .. by open gl or by simply couple of images??

Plzz help me

Comment: the easiest is probably taking a video of you pouring water from a glass to another glass, then playing it; though I doubt that would look anywhere near good.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make some decent-looking water flowing by [particle effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_system). The particles flows down by gravity and is colored transparent blue, and a little bit "foggy with a splash". For more challenge, the particles should agglutinate together into a single bigger particle when they're near each other.

You may want to look at [this tutorial](http://www.gamedev.net/columns/hardcore/rnerwater1/) if you want a truly realistic water effect and doesn't mind burning too much CPU. (I haven't really read it yet though)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you know OpenGL that would be too much work, better create an animation with other software export it as a movie or images and show that in your program ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look [at this SO question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927714/iphone-quartz-how-to-get-a-water-effect) (it points to other questions)