# In what ways is Cocos2d better the the APIs already given to you by Apple? (Just examples not opinion)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I don't want a debate... I just want examples because I thought the stuff Apple gives you is already pretty good. Are there any particular reasons that Cocos2d is better for game development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All but the most simple games will most likely want to take advantage of OpenGL. Using the inbuilt frameworks for animations & graphics will be horribly slow unless you are only doing something simple like a puzzle game. The downside of OpenGL is that for beginners it is quite difficult, and the general feeling is that you require a lot of code in order to do even simple things (eg. display a graphic onscreen). You can think of Cocos2D as a friendly interface to OpenGL. It provides all (most) of the power, but it's very easy to get started and continue working with.

Definitely recommend if you want to get into games to consider the Cocos2D framework.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple bases all of its stuff on OpenGL not just Cocos2d.

Comment: No, I don't think that is correct. Are you talking about CoreAnimation? Why do you think all serious game devs use OpenGL if Apple's framework is already backed by it? Or is this your question :) Have a look here for some more discussion between the two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845662/core-animation-or-opengl-es

Comment: @alku83: I'm pretty sure CoreAnimation is based OpenGL ES (which is the OpenGL equivalent for mobile devices) and therefore everything is based off OpenGL ES.

Comment: If you can find a link or otherwise I'm happy to stand corrected.

Comment: Hmmm... I can not find anything on it at the moment maybe I am wrong... I will keep looking for something though when I get the chance.

Comment: There is nothing showing about OpenGL ES in the headers for CoreAnimation I stand mistaken... I wonder what I was thinking about then *sigh*...

Comment: If you're wanting to use CA because you're hesitant to learn Cocos2D, don't be. It's very easy to pick up, has great performance, and there's lots of good demo code and support around. Good luck whatever direction you choose.